# How to get and change a variable's value from outside a method?

Tags: ruby, methods

I want to change an a variable by creating a method. An example is:

```
a = 0

def increase1
  a += 1
  puts a
end

increase1
```

When run this code, I get `` undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) `` error. I guess the variable `a` can't read `increase1` method, and `a` becomes `nil`. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: This smells like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. It is not possible to give a more detailed answer than a simple "No" to your question "is there any way I can handle this" without you telling us what "this" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, `a` is not defined in `increase`.

Try this:

```
a = 0

def increase1(a)
   a +=1
   puts a
end

increase1(a)
```

I hope it useful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to change a local variable in a different scope. That's why local variables are called "local" variables: because they are local to the scope they are defined in. Your two `a`s are two completely different local variables in two completely different scopes that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: That being said, if the object was mutable, you could simply pass it to the method you created and mutate it. Won't work with integers in Ruby though.

Comment: so if i use **@a** instead of **a** this problem is totally removed, is it?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej: Mutating the referenced object is something completely different from mutating the reference to the object. Since the OP hasn't told us what the actual problem is they want to solve, it is pretty much impossible to tell whether or not that would solve the problem. Also, `+=` will *always* re-bind the variable, no matter what the referenced object is, and all common implementations of `+` in the core libraries, standard libraries, and most third-party libraries are pure.

Comment: Whether or not using `@a` instead of `a` "totally removes the problem" depends on what "the problem" is that you are trying to solve, which you still haven't told us. Instance variables have totally different scope and semantics from local variables, so doing this will significantly change the semantics of your program, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @JörgWMittag which all comes down to "we don't know what OP wanted to achieve". Is mutating an object "changing a variable"? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry about my language mistakes. I'm not exactly mastered in this language and I look at the dictionary a lot of times :). Anyway, I'm creating an `a` variable and giving it a value. Then I create a few methods and these methods process using the `a` variable. Then, using an if/else statement, I call any method according to the condition. However, when I run the program and the method doesn't recognize the variable `a` I get `for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` error. To resolve this problem, I need to convert the variable `a` to global, or is there any more useful solution?